# Can Heat Change the internal potential energy of a system

Tags: thermodynamics

What I know is that heat supplying heat increases average kinetic energy of molecules, but does it has any affect on potential energy of system. I have a intution that supplying heat might decrease the potential energy. Is it possible to supply heat and have no change in kinetic energy(i.e. temperature) and have change in just potential energy.

Comment: Equating average kinetic energy and temperature means you're considering an ideal gas?

Comment: What do you call the potential energy of a system? what di you mean having an "intuition" about this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you’re talking about the internal energy of the system, I.e, the sum of the kinetic and potential energy at the molecular level. The kinetic energy is the sum of molecular translational, rotational, and vibrational molecular kinetic energy. The potential energy is that associated with intermolecular forces.

Only in the case of ideal gas behavior is the effect of heat restricted to a change in molecular kinetic energy, because the intermolecular forces are considered to be negligible. For real gases heat can cause changes in both molecular kinetic and potential energy.

It is possible for heat to cause a change in molecular potential energy without a change in molecular kinetic energy. That’s what occurs during constant temperature phase changes (e.g, between melting and freezing).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer yes I was talking about internal energy of the system.